# ¿Como puedo forzar sobrescribir ficheros locales con un git pull?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-pull

explico los detalles.

**Antecedente**
Tenemos un sitio prestashop con su control de versiones, cada vez que instalamos un modulo directamente en el servidor, creamos una rama especifica para dicha configuracion.
Una vez configurado, esta rama temporal se envia a GitLab para hacer un merge request
El merge request nos integra los cambios de la rama temporal en Master, con lo cual Master queda de la forma correcta.

**El problema**
En el server al hacer un pull desde la rama Master, nos detecta que hay "untracked files" que son los ficheros del modulo que hemos configurado e instalado en la "rama temporal"

Estos no nos interesa guardarlos porque ya se han configurado y enviado al repositorio desde donde se ha hecho el merge.

¿Como podemos hacer un pull desde el server para que nos traiga la rama Master ya mergeada ignorando los cambios que tenemos en local?

He recordar que la rama master que tenemos en GitLab ya esta perfectamente mergeada y tal cual como la queremos en el servidor

De antemano gracias por vuestra colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás seguro de que la rama master en tu repositorio remoto es la versión que quieres y puedes ignorar los cambios locales entonces puedes hacer:

`git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master`

Saludos.

PD. Por cuestiones de inclusión y equidad ya no se recomienda nombrar "master" a la rama principal de un proyecto. Ahora "main" parece un nombre más aceptado ;)

Comment: Gracias @Eduardo, efectivamente con esto me ha funcionado correctamente. Solo por indicar una mejora mas, nose si sea por mi server pero tuve que añadir --all a git fetch por lo que quedo `git fetch -all`

Comment: @JosePrimo No creo que tenga nada que ver con tu server. `--all` lo que hace es indicarle a git que haga fetch sobre todos los repositorios remotos configurados.